# How to sort NSMutableArray in objective C

Tags: iphone, ios

i am workinng on timer app.
i have a an array.i want to sort array in accending order.
suppose i have 5 element in array like 10,100,50,30,70.

I want array like 10,30,50,70,100.

Comment: Are the elements of `NSString` or `NSNUmber`

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far. Without context it's difficult to help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

Comment: The title shouldnt read "How to sort NSMutableArray in objective c" but **"How to search in Stackoverflow?"**

Answer (score 11):

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
    return [((NSString *)firstObject) compare:((NSString *)secondObject) options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

EDIT:
If the elements are numbers, change the returned type and the type of the firstObject and secondObject.

Answer (score 3):

from [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSComparator)

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Comment: You should use the compare method of NSNumber if they are NSNumbers.

Comment: He doesn't say that they're NSNumbers though...

Comment: So you can stil call the `compare:`, since it a `NSObject` method

Answer (score 2):

Use `sortedArrayUsingComparator`

```
NSArray *arr = @[@3, @2, @6, @1];
NSArray *sorted = [arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if ([obj1 intValue] < [obj2 intValue]) return NSOrderedAscending;
    else return NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```

Comment: And what if they have the same value?

Comment: There is no disadvantage to it thinking e.g. 1 < 1. What's the difference between `1, 1, 3` and `1, 1, 3`?

Comment: Try it with  `@[@3, @2, @6, @1, @1, @1, @1];`, it produces the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSArray * arr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber   numberWithInt:10],[NSNumber   numberWithInt:100],[NSNumber   numberWithInt:50],[NSNumber   numberWithInt:30],[NSNumber   numberWithInt:70], nil];
    NSLog(@"Before sorting%@",arr);

    arr = [arr sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
      NSLog(@"After sorting%@",arr);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sort" ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
self.myList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[unsortedList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]]];
```

Comment: There is no need to create the `NSSortDescriptor` you can use `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` methode with the same block.

Answer (score -2):

use this code:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
    return [((NSString *)firstObject) compare:((NSString *)secondObject) options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

EDIT: If the elements are numbers, change the returned type and the type of the firstObject and secondObject.