# How can i sort the NSMutableArray in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort NSMutableArray in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864309/how-to-sort-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c)

i want to sort the NSMutablearray which contain the value 
434,34,4,45

i am using this code for sorting:

```
[arrayfinale sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

but it return:

> 45,4,34,433

but i want

> 4,34,45,433

can anybody help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 5):

from [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSComparator)

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Comment: @thanx john it is working fine

Comment: But what about NSMutableArray ? How to sort it?

Answer (score 3):

Use Following code

```
   NSArray *unsortedArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"60", @"4", @"60", @"50", @"12", @"10", @"1", nil];
   NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
   return [((NSString *)firstObject) compare:((NSString *)secondObject) options:NSNumericSearch]; }];
   NSLog(@"Array is ::%@",sortedArray);
```